# How to convert a multi-page PDF table to a spreadsheet format?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftotext

I have a huge PDF file with 300+ pages on which a big 10+ column table is spread. I am using Linux and would like to have a simple command line command which would convert this table to a text importable to a spreadsheet.

Currently I am using `pdftotext -layout`, and gives quite good results, other than every page is considered independently and column widths and positions change from page to page (due to different maximum column *content* width on each page), so I cannot simply import the resulting text file to a spreadsheet application and split it to columns by a fixed column width.

I have tried to crop every column on every page (their position is identical across the whole PDF file), but in the result the empty rows are merged together, so the rows with content will be shifted with respect to each other.

If `pdftotext` had an option to convert the file with a **STRICT LAYOUT** (not by column content width), that would help. Or if I could stack all pages in PDF file to a single page, that could also solve it.

What are the options to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the nature of the content of a PDF file. There are no tables in PDf, there is no metadata (generally) to describe the content as a table. The text you see on the page may not be laid out in the reading order.

For example the PDF file might contain a line of text drawn at the top of the page, then one at the bottom, then a paragraph in the middle before jumping back up to the top for a headline.

In addition there may be no spaces between two text fragments. Text is drawn at an absolute position on the page, so you can draw (for example ) cell A, then move the current point by say 1 cm, rthen draw cell B and so on. Since there's no 'space' characters between the two cells, a naive text extraction will, naturally, assume the two lines of text are coninuous.

The **STRICT LAYOUT** you want isn't impossible, but you can't do it with a simple text file, because the original layout isn't made up of simple text characters, sometimes the space between two characters, or two fragments of text is done by moving the current point before drawing the text.

Ghostscript's txtwrite device in its simplest mode attempts to replicate the layout by replacing the white space with actual space characters in a fixed pitch font. This 'might' be good enough for you, but it equally well might not. That's because it operates by defining the smallest distance used on the page as being one space character. All distances between text is then replaced by a number of space characters, as many as are required to make up the space. This can (and often does) result in very wide output files with a **lot** of white space.

Essentially what you seem to want isn't really possible, you can't take a rich format like PDF and replicate it, including the layout, with nothing more than text characters.